# How to authorize user with Google in OS X Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, firebase, google-authentication

I am using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) in my OS X application. I am trying to add Google Authentication. This is an [example for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/google.html).

Question is: How to obtain Google OAuth access token in OS X application?

Comment: I believe Google Sign-In SDK is built for iOS so the cocoapods installer won't work for OS X . So, Googles [OAuth 2](https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2/wiki) may the only way to go - although the examples at that link are pretty outdated. It would be great if there was better support for OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to obtain Google OAuth 2 token in Objective-C with. [GTMOAuth2](https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth2). Using cocoapods:

```
pod 'GTMOAuth2'
```

GTMOAuth2 library needs client id with application type `other`. It is possible to create one in Google Developer Console:

[image]

This a code sample describing how to work with this lib:

```
#import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2WindowController.h"

...

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * = [GTMOAuth2WindowController
               authForGoogleFromKeychainForName: @"where-to-store-token-in-a-keychain" 
                                       clientID: @"client-id"
                                   clientSecret: @"client-secret"];

    if (authorizer.canAuthorize) {
        NSLog(@"Your authorizer was restored from key chain and can be autorized. Authorozer: %@", authorizer);
    }
    else {
        NSBundle * frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[GTMOAuth2WindowController class]];
        GTMOAuth2WindowController * windowController;
        windowController = [GTMOAuth2WindowController controllerWithScope: @"" //scope url here, empty is just email and profile
                                                             clientID: clientID
                                                         clientSecret: clientSecret
                                                     keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName
                                                       resourceBundle: frameworkBundle];

        [windowController signInSheetModalForWindow: [self window]
                              completionHandler: ^(GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth, NSError * error) {
                                                    if (error == nil) {
                                                        authorizer = auth;
                                                        NSLog(@"Successfully signed in.");
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSLog(@"Failed to sign in.");
                                                    }
                              }];
}
```

It will create pop-up window with Google authorization page inside on a first launch and use *"token"* stored in keychain for subsequent runs.

#### Pros

This authorizer can be used with almost every Google Service.

#### Cons

Looks like it can not be easily integrated with Firebase.

Comment: I've added an answer below that might help.

Comment: The other option is no longer available now.  What to do?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase auth can be integrated with Google sign in on OS X the following way using the `GTMOAuth2` pod.

```
import Cocoa
import GTMOAuth2
import Firebase

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://xyz.firebaseio.com")

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()


    let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: GTMOAuth2WindowController.self)
    let windowController = GTMOAuth2WindowController(scope: "", clientID: clientID, clientSecret: clientSecret, keychainItemName: keychainName, resourceBundle: frameworkBundle)
    windowController.signInSheetModalForWindow(window, delegate: self, finishedSelector: #selector(MainWindowController.didFinishWithAuth(windowController:auth:error:)))

}

func didFinishWithAuth(windowController wc:GTMOAuth2WindowController, auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication, error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        print(auth)
        ref.authWithOAuthProvider("google", token: auth.accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { err, auth in
            if err != nil {
                print(err)
            } else {
                print(auth)
            }
        })
      }
  }
}
```

A couple of things to notice, as brainless mentioned above, you have to create an OAuth Api key using the `other` option in the credentials manager. You have to remember to white list your clientID in your firebase project.

Comment: I'm unable to find Other Options in Console. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Updated code for recent versions of Firebase. Signing in with Google (using OAuth) to authenticate with Firebase.

```
func someFunc {
    let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: GTMOAuth2WindowController.self)
    let windowController = GTMOAuth2WindowController(scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", clientID: YOUR_CLIENT_ID, clientSecret: YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET, keychainItemName: "OAuth2 APP_NAME: Google+", resourceBundle: frameworkBundle)

    guard let window = self.view.window else { return }

    windowController?.signInSheetModal(for: window, delegate: self, finishedSelector: #selector(didFinishWithAuth(windowController:auth:error:)))
}

  @objc func didFinishWithAuth(windowController:GTMOAuth2WindowController, auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication, error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
      print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
    } else {

      let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: GoogleAuthProviderID, accessToken: auth.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (auth, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
          }

          // Successful sign in
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this update based on one of the existing answers? If so, it'd be worth acknowledging whose answer it was based on, to help share credit where due.