# How login to Google using google SDK in OSX (Mac)

Tags: swift, macos, sdk, google-signin

I found [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) to integrating Google Login SDK in my iOS app & there was no problem.

Now I want to do the same on the Mac version of my app but I couldn't find any SDK for that!

I googled it and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234544/how-to-authorize-user-with-google-in-os-x-cocoa-application) which says I could use firebase login instead.

So I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276695/does-firebase-still-support-mac-os-x-july-2016) to integrate FireBase:

But I'm stuck at integrating FireBase because when I update my podfile
I get this error:

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore"
```

I also tried this: pod 'FirebaseOSX', '>= 2.4.2'
But I got this error:

```
Specs satisfying the `FirebaseOSX (>= 2.4.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

So I am Stuck!
is there any simple or better way to integrate Google Login in my OSX app?

Comment: What deployment target are you setting? The error says you need to set a higher version.

Comment: The minimum available deployment target is 10.6

Comment: Any reason for setting such an old target OS?

Comment: I tested newer versions too but got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried GTMAppAuth? : [here](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth/tree/master/Examples/Example-macOS). 
You can use it for both iOS and Mac.